# Group by another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to do

```
 @Query(value = "select client, sum(price) from PizzaOrder group by client")
 public List<?> topClients();
```

Where **PizzaOrder** contains these fields:

```
private Double price;

@ManyToOne
private Client client;
```

Also **Client** class has defined equals and hashCode.

The error:

```
Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List packageName.PizzaOrderRepository.topClients()
```

Comment: Is there any more information in the error message? If so please post the _complete_ error. If not, did you try and verify that the group-by clause is what causes the error?

Comment: Not all versions of Hibernate support `group by entity` so try `group by entity.id` instead - and if you like (kidding, you normally should do that) tell us which version of Hibernate you are using.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think the problem is with `group by entity`, that query has no alias for PizzaOrder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query should look like:

```
 @Query(value = "select p.client, sum(p.price) from PizzaOrder p group by p.client")
 public List<?> topClients();
```

See [this HQL docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm)